# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure for google-client-api

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-calendar-api, tls1.2, java-11, google-client

**I am trying to fetch google-calendar using google-client-api but facing below error:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:322)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:346)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:398)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:494)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:880)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeJobExecutionListener.beforeJob(CompositeJobExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:298)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Below is the piece of code causing error:**

```
calendarList = getGoogleCalendarServiceInstance(googleCredential).calendarList().list()
                .setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
```

**build.gradle is as below:**

```
#!groovy

ext {
    googleApiVersion = '1.17.0-rc'
    googleCalendarApiVersion = 'v3-rev74-1.17.0-rc'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: "${googleApiVersion}"
    compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-jackson2', version: "${googleApiVersion}"
    compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-calendar', version: "${googleCalendarApiVersion}"
}
```

**Note sure whether certificate is causing the error or I'm missing some dependency?
Please suggest.**

**Note: We are have migrated from java-8 to java-11 and currently using bundle jre.**

Answer (score 8):

Posting the answer as it might be helpful for others facing  the same probelm.

The issue was getting generated because "EC cipher suites were missing".
The handshake failed immediately after ClientHello as the server didn't support any of the cipher suites sent by the client.

**I found this solution at** https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221674

Below change fixed my issue:

specifying the provider in add-modules :

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jlink.exe --module-path "mods" --add-modules=test,jdk.crypto.ec --output jre
```